# jQuery change media query width value

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

Is it possible with `jQuery` or anything else to change width value of `@media query` `css` while page is running?

So for example if in style.css I've got

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
   /*whatever*/
}
```

to change it to `500px` after website is loaded

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but WHY?

Comment: I too come with same requirement.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but to respond to @jQuery00, I need to be able to adjust the min-width on different devices if more content has been added or removed.

Comment: This would be helpful for me too. I need to expand an iframe if there's a resize or rotation event. I could write it all in javascript, but changing one parameter in my @media query would be simpler, cleaner, more elegant.

Comment: plus to @TonyBrasunas point, graphics-intensive CSS is rendered on GPU, hence a much better performance than JS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible through traditional method. You have to insert the full css through jQuery. For e.g :

```
 $('body').append("<style type='text/css'>@media screen and (min-width: 500px) { /*whatever*/ }</style>");
```