# How to change the css inside a @media print query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

When the contents of a div are too large I need to scale them before printing. I've followed the helpful advice here and set up printing stylesheets. When it comes time to print I find I need to change some of the css inside the @media print query. Instead of changing the class in the media query, I find a regular CSS selector makes the changes to the div on the screen and not in the print query. Is there a selector I can use to make the changes to the @media print css only?

Example here: Hitting the 'Change Scale' button immediately zooms the image. I want the changed scale to only apply upon printout.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
function draw_a() {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
//   //  LEVER

//plane
context.fillStyle   = '#aaa';
context.fillRect  (25, 90, 2500, 400);


}




function changeScale() {
  
  var scale = .1;
  
  console.log("scale:" + scale);
  
   $('.myDivToPrint').css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                '-o-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
             
            });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  draw_a();
  
});
```

```css
div.sizePage {
  color: #333;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.printOnly {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3);
        transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3); /* Standard Property */
        position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /*
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
 */
  
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="window.print();" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
<button onclick="changeScale();" class="no-print>">Change Scale</button>
<div class="myDivToPrint">
<canvas height="2500px" width="4000px" id="canvas1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Selectors inside the `@media print` query already apply to print only. Seems like you already do what you need. Could you please clarify?

Comment: In the code snippet when the 'Change Scale' button is clicked you can see the image on the screen actually change scale. This indicates to me that the browser created some other class (maybe an element) and applied it to the div on the screen. The actual class in the media query is untouched. I will try to update the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. You would you like to edit the Media Query itself. In which case here are a few examples. 
[jQuery change media query width value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147532/jquery-change-media-query-width-value)

```
$('body').append("<style type='text/css'>@media screen and (min-width: 500px) { /*whatever*/ }</style>");
```

You can also use window.MatchMedia() as show in the sample below!
https://codepen.io/ravenous/pen/BgGKA

You can just update an existing  element (or create one) textContent to contain the rule, which will make it effective in the given context.
[Generating CSS media queries with javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050926/generating-css-media-queries-with-javascript-or-jquery)

```
document.querySelector('style').textContent +=
    "@media screen and (min-width:400px) { div { color: red; }}"
```

There is also a Library which allows the mixture of CSS and jQuery specific for this purpose.
http://www.learningjquery.com/2017/03/how-to-use-media-queries-with-jquery

Comment: These look promising. I'm trying to modify the code snippet that implements one and failing so far. Could you create a code snippet showing how it works? Thanks,
Matt

Comment: if( CONDITIONS) { document.querySelector('style').textContent +=
    "@media print { div { color: red; }}"; }

Comment: Please Accept Answer ! :) Any one of these would work, but remember SO is for reference!