# Programmatically add/change a style tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202655/how-to-change-the-css-inside-a-media-print-query) it has been suggested I can update a media query dynamically by editing an elements 'style' tag. I know it can be done with jquery using the .css method, however apparently the style tag itself needs to be updated.

My ultimate goal is to append the entire media query which I can't do with the, as noted here, better approaches of .css. If I use .css then what changes is the class on the screen and the media query. However, I only want to change the media query. The question is my attempt I'm trying to just change the font color in the style tag and so far not having luck.

I appreciate all the responses so far.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
function myFunction() {
    $('.changeMe').append("<style type='text/css'>color:blue</>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change text from black to blue</button>
<p class="changeMe">Change My Color To Blue by adding a style tag</p>
```

Here is a code snippet that shows using .css changes the div on the screen which I do not want.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
function draw_a() {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
//   //  LEVER

//plane
context.fillStyle   = '#aaa';
context.fillRect  (25, 90, 2500, 400);


}




function changeScale() {
  
  var scale = .1;
  
  console.log("scale:" + scale);
  
   $('.myDivToPrint').css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                '-o-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
             
            });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  draw_a();
  
});
```

```css
div.sizePage {
  color: #333;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.printOnly {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3);
        transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.3); /* Standard Property */
        position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /*
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
 */
  
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="window.print();" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
<button onclick="changeScale();" class="no-print>">Change Scale (Want this to only change scale in media query.)</button>
<div class="myDivToPrint">
<canvas height="2500px" width="4000px" id="canvas1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is a code snippet that would, I think add the media query I need.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
function draw_a() {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
//   //  LEVER

//plane
context.fillStyle   = '#aaa';
context.fillRect  (25, 90, 2500, 400);


}




function changeScale() {
  
  var scale = .1;
  
  console.log("scale:" + scale);
  
   $('.myDivToPrint').append("<style type='text/css'>@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none){"
                    + "-webkit-transform: scale(" + scale + ") translate(100px,100px) rotate(-90deg),"
                    + "-moz-transform: scale(" + scale + ") translate(100px,100px) rotate(-90deg),"
                    + "-ms-transform: -transform: scale(" + scale + ") translate(100px,100px) rotate(-90deg),"
                    + "-o-transform: scale(" + scale + ") translate(100px,100px) rotate(-90deg),"
                    + "transform: scale(" + scale + ") translate(100px,100px) rotate(-90deg),"
                + "</style>");

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  draw_a();
  
});
```

```css
div.sizePage {
  color: #333;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.printOnly {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
  }
  .myDivToPrint {
    background-color: yellow;
        position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 
  
  }
  .no-print,
  .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printOnly {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="window.print();" class="no-print">Print Canvas</button>
<button onclick="changeScale();" class="no-print>">Change Scale</button>
<div class="myDivToPrint">
<canvas height="2500px" width="4000px" id="canvas1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: please read the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/) as it will explain the correct way to apply jQuery css dynamically.

Comment: So a better design is not doing this and using themes....

Comment: I left an answer OP, but I'm not 100% why you want to update media queries as opposed to altering the style of jQuery-targeted elements.

Comment: It can be done, but there's *so* many better ways than hacking around a `style` element

Comment: You say that you must edit the style tags its self which implies inline styling. You're not using inline styling.  Further more, to want to edit the actual style tag in the DOM is.. strange. Why/what is your reasoning for having to change tag instead of just applying the CSS directly?

Comment: Does the ''style tag' you mention already exist on the page by default?

Comment: OP please also add your media query.

Comment: ProEvilz, I added updates that I hope answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

To alter the CSS of a given element with jQuery, you can use it's `.css()` function. Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

The first value in the function defines which property you want to change (in our case it's color) and the second is the value you wish to apply to it (in our case it's blue)

```
function myFunction() {
    $('.changeMe').css("color","blue");
}
```

To give more clarity, this can be used for any CSS pretty much. E.G.

```
//change BG color
.css('background-color', 'red');

//change width
.css('width', '100px');

//change font size
.css('font-size', '16px');
```

Comment: I think because the OP asked how to change a media query with jQuery, not just modify the css styles?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I do think it was downvoted because the question states I tried this and it didn't work for my purpose which is to change the css of a media query and not onscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Issue #1 In your current setup it will just produce this (you are basically appending inside your paragraph):

```
<p class="changeMe">Change My Color To Blue by adding a style tag<style type="text/css">color:blue</></style></p>
```

Issue #2 (once you resolve issue 1) What happens if your user keeps pounding that button? It will keep appending more and more style tags on there

A better way of doing this would be to just target you existing element class

```
<p class="changeMe">Change My Color To Blue by adding a style tag</p>
```

Add a style element to the page and that targets that class and just replace the entire contents on change needed:

```
<style class="changeMe_styles">
</style>
```

In JS on event occurrence

```
$(".changeMe_styles").text("@media (min-width: 900px) {.changeMe{ color: blue;}}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to prepend a whole style tag to an element. Here, I've used the jQuery `.css()` method to change the colour.

Have a read up about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```js
function myFunction() {
    $('.changeMe').css("color", "blue")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change text from black to blue</button>
<p class="changeMe">Change My Color To Blue by adding a style tag</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and usually this would be correct. However, I need to change the css of a media query. I tried modifying an existing media query with .css but it only modified the screen css. So, adding a style tag is my attempt to circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off actually.  Try appending the entire media query and it's contents to the body/head(can't remember how each behave in this circumstance):

```
function myFunction()
  {
    $('body').append("<style type='text/css'>@media screen and (min-width: 500px) { /*styling stuff*/ }</style>");
  }
```

Obviously, you can change the media query type.  I've seen that used before with success so good luck.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to append the entire media query which I can't do with the, as noted here, better approaches of .css. If I use .css then what changes is the class on the screen and the media query. However, I only want to change the media query. The question is my attempt I'm trying to just change the font color in the style tag and so far not having luck.

Comment: @MatthewDavidJankowski So if I understand correctly, you only want to change the styles **inside** the media query?

Comment: @ProEvilz @Mathew Either that or he want to update the actual media query?  He might want to change the `min-width` or add `max-width`?

Comment: I need to scale a canvas image combined with embedded svgs for a printout and, thus far, have found the css transform properties hold the most promise. Here is that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202655/how-to-change-the-css-inside-a-media-print-query

Comment: This is really confusing... you need to more clear and precise as to what you need.

Comment: Was just about to say the same thing.  That comment sounds nothing like the original question.  OP I suggest you update your original question stating the end goal as you have here.

Comment: Apologies proEvilz. I think the original question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202655/how-to-change-the-css-inside-a-media-print-query)  was more clear. This question was asked in an attempt to implement the answer to that question and instead morphed into something resembling my original question.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to append in p tag. It will only append in `head`.

```
function myFunction() {
    $(head).append("<style type='text/css'>color:blue</>")
}
```

Comment: This is just as useful as using `css()` because this doesn't alter the already **existing style tag** that OP wants to **edit**

Comment: While this does highlight an issue with his current code, it does not actually answer his question nor is it a viable answer as the function would continue to append every time the function is called without a thought to the previously appended styles.

Comment: @TravisActon yes right but we can take reference from this